# Why do I get None as a result

Tags: python

I have the following script:

```
import math
scores = [3.0,1.0,0.1]
sum = 0
i=0
j=0

for s in scores:
    sum = sum + math.exp(scores[i])
    i=i+1

def myFunction(x):
    math.exp(x)/sum

for s2 in scores:
    print(myFunction(scores[j]))
    j=j+1
```

But, the output I get is:

```
None
None
None
```

Why is that? How can I retrieve the correct values?

Thanks.

Comment: `myFunction()` doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: And by default, a function that doesn't explicitly return anything returns `None`.

Comment: This is not `ruby`. This is `python`. You need explicit `return` statement.

Comment: As your `def` does not return anything, you print that nothing `None`. OFF: This title with 8314 rep? Man...

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return.

```
def myFunction(x):
    return math.exp(x)/sum
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(myFunction(scores[j]))`
Here you try to print something. But myFunction doesn't return anything to print.

You can use,

`def myFunction(x):
  return math.exp(x)/sum`

This will solve the problem.